# Can Magento 1.9 be stateless?

Tags: kubernetes, magento-1.9, stateless

I am trying to deploy a `Magento` 1.9 store on a `Kubernetes` cluster. A major concern I have is the "statelessness" of Magento. More specifically:

1. Can I use an S3 for all my `media/` directory?
2. Can config (and other types of) files that Magento keeps in the file system be bundled up with in a Docker file?

What I mean is that I need to NOT use a `PersistentVolume` and be able to think as my pods (containers) as entities that I can restart often and with no worries of data/config inconsistency. For instance, `Django` or `NodeJS` can perfectly fit this description, but this is not the case with `WordPress`, which is why I worry I'll have difficulties with its `PhP` brother `Magento`...

**I AM TALKING ABOUT Magento 1.9 NOT 2**